# highchartjs create label for column

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hello I have a column Chart which displays servers. The X-axis shows how much they are used and the Y-axis counts them. Now I have for every group (with group I mean all Server on acolumn like "0-5%") an array of the server names. I would like to display this array in the right corner when I hover them like here with the value: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/)

This is the code I already have the obj are Arrays which count the servers:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Server Disk root used in %'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'All Linux Servers'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Anzahl Server'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Anzahl Server: <b>{point.y}</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Server',
            data: [
                ['0-5%',   obj2],
                ['5-10%',  obj5],
                ['10-15%', obj8],
                ['15-20%', obj11],
                ['20-25%', obj14],
                ['25-30%', obj17],
                ['30-35%', obj20],
                ['35-40%', obj23],
                ['40-45%', obj26],
                ['45-50%', obj29],
                ['50-55%', obj32],
                ['55-60%', obj35],
                ['60-65%', obj38],
                ['65-70%', obj41],
                ['70-100%',obj44]

            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y}', // one decimal
                 y: 5,// 5 pixels down from the top
                style: {


     fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Here is a picture of my Chart:

[image]

The Arrays which I want to dsiplay when hover look like that 
`obj1 = ["server11", "server1125", "server1127"]`
For every column there is an array like that this one is the array for the 0-5% column.

Comment: You can use [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and then extract extra fields from this.options.yourfieldnames

Answer (score 3):

You need to use tooltip positioner function and define x,y coordinates where you want to show it.

```
  positioner: function () {
            return { x: 500, y: 30 };
        }
```

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/trusm77t/4/)

Comment: Okay that helped but as I said I have an array with the Servernames of every column and i like to display them when I hover over a particular column do you know how to do this?

Comment: yes, that's easy.just use formatter function to return servername.If you can share your data so that I can create fiddle for you. this.category will return name,or point.x depending on your data

Comment: I updated the question and added one of the arrays for the first column the other arrays loke the same just with more servernames.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided itself answers it. Not sure where you are getting stuck? Could you elaborate?

You need to use mouseOver and mouseOut event functions inside plotOptions to define what needs to be show when hovering over the data points.

Comment: I have an arrays of every column which looks like array0-5%=[servername2][servername4].... And now I want to show this names when I hover over the columns.